# Find the image of a given value in a relation

Tags: relation, set-theory, z-notation, mathematical-notation

I have a relation R given below:

```
R = {(a,1), (a,2), (b,1)}
```

To get the image set of *a*, we can write `R(|{a}|) = {1,2}` in Z notation, using thick brackets symbol (| |).

Is there a mathematical symbol to represent this rather than using the Z notation? Can we have R(a) like what we usually do to get a function image of a given value, e.g. f(a)?

Answer (score 0):

In mathematics, using brackets is common: `R[{a}] = {1,2}`

See also [math. image in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_(mathematics)).